# C Program to detect right angled triangles

Tags: c, algorithm

If I am given 100 points in the coordinate system, and I have to find if there exist a right angled triangle in those vertices.
Is there a way that I can detect the right angled triangle among those vertices without having to choose all pairs of 3 vertices and then applying Pythagoras theorem on them??
Can there be a better algorithm for this?
Thanks for any help. :)

Comment: You could find the vectors for all the pairs of points (p1 - p2) and then check the dot product of which 2 vectors (with one common end point) results in a zero.

Comment: But if I have 100 points then taking every possible subset of 2 points wont be a more time consuming task??

Comment: 100 points is not that many. Just implement the naive algorithm, it won't take long anyway.

Comment: Agreed, 100 points means there are fewer than 1 million triangle to check for right-ness. Even brute-force won't take long.

Comment: 100 points generates 9900 vectors.  For each vector you need to consider at most 98 other vectors.  That's less than 1,000,000 dot products altogether.  If you're clever, you can do it with fewer than 500,000 dot products.  That's totally doable.

Comment: Another factor to consider is floating point errors. Defining a right-angle triangle is easy with exact arithmetic but selecting an appropriate tolerance to do this in floating point arithmetic will depend on the particular case. If you just want the triangle that is closest to being a right angle, that would be straightforward but then that triangle might not necessarily be very close to being right-angled.

Comment: @JohnBollinger So, I shall take every possible pair of points, then calculate a vector with them and then take the dot with every other possible vector?? :O

Comment: Are the point's x,y co-ordinates integer or floating point?

Comment: @chux They are integers..

Comment: Suggest posting your implementation of "choose all sets of 3 vertices and then applying Pythagoras theorem".  By you doing step 1, it would be a good reference as any better solution could be tested against that for speed and correctness.  That would help us provide better answers.

Comment: This question is about a mathematical algorithm, not about programming. Maybe try math.so or cs.so?

Comment: You wouldn't happen to be working in two dimensions only, would you?

Comment: If they're integers you should *definitely* look for an arithmetic solution; I can't offer specifics but you can probably rule out a ton of combinations by looking at divisors and such.

Comment: @alexis That is what I am trying to figure out sir, a way to rule out those combinations.

Comment: Well, you're on the wrong site in my opinion, and you'd left out the all-important information that these are integers. You should really try one of the sites I suggested, you're more likely to get an expert answer.

Comment: You say you are looking for a 'better algorithm'. In what way should it be better? Normally the obvious solution is best because its easiest to write, debug and maintain - and your solution seems obvious. If you are trying to optimize it please say so and tell us about what machine it is running on and why speed is so critical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an **O(n^2 log n)-time** algorithm for **two dimensions only**. I'll describe what goes wrong in higher dimensions.

Let S be the set of points, which have integer coordinates. For each point o in S, construct the set of nonzero vectors V(o) = {p - o | p in S - {o}} and test whether V(o) contains two orthogonal vectors in linear time as follows.

Method 1: canonize each vector (x, y) to (x/gcd(x, y), y/gcd(x, y)), where |gcd(x, y)| is the largest integer that divides both x and y, and where gcd(x, y) is negative if y is negative, positive if y is positive, and |x| if y is zero. (This is very similar to putting a fraction in lowest terms.) The key fact about two dimensions is that, for each nonzero vector, there exists exactly one canonical vector orthogonal to that vector, specifically, the canonization of (-y, x). Insert the canonization of each vector in V(o) into a set data structure and then, for each vector in V(o), look up its canonical orthogonal mate in that data structure. I'm assuming that the gcd and/or set operations take time O(log n).

Method 2: define a comparator on vectors as follows. Given vectors `(a, b), (c, d)`, write `(a, b) < (c, d)` if and only if

```
s1 s2 (a d - b c) < 0,
```

where

```
s1 = -1 if b < 0 or (b == 0 and a < 0)
      1 otherwise
s2 = -1 if d < 0 or (d == 0 and c < 0)
      1 otherwise.
```

Sort the vectors using this comparator. (This is very similar to comparing the fraction `a/b` with `c/d`.) For each vector (x, y) in V(o), binary search for its orthogonal mate (-y, x).

In three dimensions, the set of vectors orthogonal to the unit vector along the z-axis is the entire x-y-plane, and the equivalent of canonization fails to map all vectors in this plane to one orthogonal mate.

Comment: Thank you so much for looking into it sir. But can you please explain the canonization thing a bit more? Like whats the use of canonization? (Dividing by the gcd(x,y))? Further I have `n` points then forming vectors choosing all the other points will be O(n^2) right? and then checking all the other vectors formed for orthogonal property will be O(n) (Linearly looking at all vectors?) So, it would be O(n^2), no? How can it be `O(n^2logn)`?? Please explain.. Thanks.. :)

Comment: @user007 It's like putting a fraction in least terms. If we assume that gcd is constant time and that we have access to a hash set, then yes, the running time would be O(n^2).

Comment: Simpler: for each point, sort the other points by angle and then find if there's two that are orthogonal in O(n). Overall, O(n^2.log(n)) same as your solution.

Comment: @Anonymous If you trust your `atan2` not to have spurious collisions, then sure. The problem is that, e.g., `atan2(pow(2, 31) - 1, 1) == atan2(pow(2, 31) - 2, 1)` with IEEE doubles. The second comparator sorts by angle using integer arithmetic.