# Finding weight value of isosceles right angled triangles

Tags: algorithm, combinations, permutation, dynamic-programming

I want to find out the weight value of total number of isosceles right angled triangles inside a n*m rectangular grid. The weight value is the value which is total of adding each point value in the rectangular grid. Let me explain through an example

[image]

Here is the rectangular grid with n=1 and m=2. I want to find out the weight of each isosceles right angled triagle present in this grid. Here are the possible right angle isosceles triangles which can be formed from this grid

[image]

So I want to find out the weight value of each of these triangles like triangle A has 4, B has 6.
I tried finding total number of right angled triangles using [C Program to detect right angled triangles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26223467/c-program-to-detect-right-angled-triangles) but it is difficult to find each triangle's weight if I would only know how many triangles there are. My approach for this problem was picking every point and find the triangle associated with it and the corresponding weight value.  But it takes 4 times the time complexity the number of points in the grid (4 times 2*3 in this case). I want to find an efficient formula so that I can perform this operation for large n and m as well. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In you example - why have you changed the colours for the nodes?

Comment: The C++ tag feels wrong. This is a computer-science problem; the solution is very likely identical in every programming language (or at least in every imperative programming language).

Comment: @ChristianHackl Sorry. I have removed C++ tag.

Comment: Is the weight the sum of the vertices, the sum of points on the edge, or the sum of the interior of the triangle?  It will matter to how hard this is.

Comment: @btilly The weight is the sum of points on triangle like for E it is sum of 3,2,0,0 which is 5

Comment: Can we assume that all "nodes" are exactly 1 unit apart?

Comment: @JTY Yes, 1 unit apart.

Comment: One way to do this is figure out on how many triangles a node lies, then multiply its weight with that number, and sum all those products up. The number of such triangles is a function of the n, m, and the coordinates of the node. This will give you linear time, which is optimal.

Comment: @G.Bach I need to find out the weight of individual triangle.

Comment: Then you'll have to enumerate them.

Comment: @G.Bach How can I do that?

Comment: @AkshayKumar as GBach has mentioned, the best thing you can do is list out all possible Traingle formations and calculate the weight for each. This will involve a whole bunch of loops as the number of triangles present in the grid rises exponentially in conjunction with the value n and m.

Comment: @JTY Polynomial, not exponential.  See my answer for details.

Comment: @btilly Sorry bout that, you are right, I meant polynomial.

Comment: do you need the sum of all the weights or the sums for each individual triangle ?

Answer (score 1):

Per the discussion in the comments, you're looking to enumerate all of the possible triangles and discover the sum of all of the points on the edges.

You can enumerate the triangles as follows.  Given a point `p = (p1, p2)` and another  point `q = (q1, q2)` there is exactly one right angled isosceles starting at `p`, going to `q` and turning right.  The third vertex will be at `r = (q1 + q2 - p2, q2 - q1 + p1)`.  If you loop over all pairs of vertices, this will find every possible triangle exactly once.

Next we need the weight of each line segment.  Given a line segment from `p` to `q`, first find the GCD of `(q1 - p1, q2 - p2)`.  (Special case.  The GCD of any integer and 0 is 1.)  Then divide both coefficients by that GCD to get the smallest vector along that line going from point to point.  Let's call that smallest vector `v`.  Now you can add up the weights for `p, p+v, p+2v, ...` then stop at `q`.  (Note, each line interval should include one point and not the other.)

And there you go.  The final algorithm should be `O(n^2 m^2 log(n+m))`.  Which can't be improved much given that the number of right-angled isosceles triangles is `O(n^2 m^2)`.  If needed you could improve the log factor by making the weight of `(starting point, unit vector, n)` recursive then memoizing it.  However that requires a `O(n^2 m^2)` data structure and locality problems addressing it could easily exceed the theoretical performance gain.

---

OK, improvement!  Instead of iterating over pairs of points, iterate over starting vectors `v = (v1, v2)` with `(v1, v2)` relatively prime (check with the Euclidean algorithm, then over starting points `p = (p1, p2)`, then over multiples `i` of the starting vector.  The triangles that you are considering will be `(p1, p2), (p1 + n*v1, p2 + n*v2), (p1 + n*v1 + n*v2, p2 - n*v1 + n*v2)`.  And NOW for each starting vector, each value of `p2 - p1`, and each of the 3 directions you could be going, you can calculate the sum of all of the weights you could have from infinity to each point on that line.  (A `O(nm)` data structure.)  With that data structure the two inner loops can execute in time `O(1)` per triangle.

This gives you a `O(n^2 m^2)` algorithm to find the total weight of all `O(n^2 * m^2)` right-angled isosceles triangles.  Which is as good as you could theoretically do.  (And the auxiliary data structures required are `O(nm)`.)